# Where is deployed content for JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss

I am new to JBoss AS 7. I have tried to deploy my war file on JBoss AS 7, which seems working fine. My question is where I can see the deployed content.

I would expect it to be like Tomcat, it should have a explored war folder some where to hold the deployed content. Is there such thing for JBoss AS 7.

Answer (score 9):

It should be in **JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments** [see there](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Developing+Applications+Guide)

If you deploy a war file name as 'sample' then you could see this file domain/configuration/domain.xml as

```
   [...]
<deployments>
   <deployment name="sample.war"
               runtime-name="sample.war">
       <content sha1="dda9881fa7811b22f1424b4c5acccb13c71202bd"/>
   </deployment>
</deployments>
[...]
<server-groups>
   <server-group name="main-server-group" profile="default">
       [...]
       <deployments>
           <deployment name="sample.war" runtime-name="sample.war"/>
       </deployments>
   </server-group>
</server-groups>
[...]
```

ls domain/content/

```
  |---/47
  |-----95cc29338b5049e238941231b36b3946952991
  |---/dd
  |-----a9881fa7811b22f1424b4c5acccb13c71202bd
```

This works for standalone/content as well.

Note that in the standalone.xml file, as referenced above, the sample.war file has a hash.  The hash is the key to locating the WAR file.  You will not find it by searching for "sample.war" in the 'content' directory though.  First 2 characters of hash is parent directory.  The rest is the directory containing the WAR file.  However the WAR file has been renamed to 'content'

```
  |---/47
  |-----95cc29338b5049e238941231b36b3946952991
  |---/dd
  |-----a9881fa7811b22f1424b4c5acccb13c71202bd
  |-------content   <-- this is really sample.war file.  JBoss renames it. (go figure!)
```

do a jar -xvf content and you will see all the class, web.xml, etc files for sample.war

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a instruction of deployment. What I am interested is after the deployment, where can I find the explored content. Thanks

Comment: Refer this link also.                                 https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Application+deployment

Answer (score 1):

Alternative way to deploy: `maven-jboss-as-plugin`.

You simply run

```
mvn deploy
```

And it deploys your war.

Answer (score 0):

you can find your deployed jars here:
$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment/