# Could not found deployment directory in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss7.x

When I upload myapp.war file to `JBoss 7.1.1` to deploy my web application, I could not find `myapp.war` folder under `/standalone/deployments' directory.

Where can I find my application directory in `JBoss 7.1.1`?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 7.1.1 has vfs (virtual filesystem) deployment. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089387/where-is-deployed-content-for-jboss7/12089447#12089447) out for more details