# How to clean JBoss AS 7.1.1 in IntelliJ + JRebel

Tags: jboss, intellij-idea, jrebel

I recently stated using IntelliJ + JRebel and like it so far.

There is just one thing which is kind of annoying. You can't see the content of the JBoss deployment directory as you can for Eclipse (where you see all files currently deployed).

As far as I understood IntelliJ is starting JBoss in a specific way that it points to the directory were the archive (ear/war/whatever) is compiled to.

But now I am facing a problem that IntelliJ seems to have an old version of my war somewhere (I can't find it in the target folder where the war is created), and tries to deploy my app twice.

I get the following error

```
 14:10:55,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment:66] JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "B-webapp.war"
 14:10:55,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment:66] JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "A-webapp.war"
 14:10:55,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner:266] JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /Users/macbook15/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
```

after that I get a failure that JBoss can't find the war for webapp B

```
 14:10:55,159 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail:94] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CRF-webapp.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CRF-webapp.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "CRF-webapp.war"
```

pointing that it can't find the war file

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/macbook15/Downloads/repo.hg/naiis-webapp/target/CRF-webapp.war (No such file or directory)
```

Is there any cache held in IntelliJ or another place were this information (that there is another app to deploy) might be still stored.

Thanks for any help

Comment: what happens if you start without JRebel? If you have JRebel enabled and rebel.xml is there, then JRebel makes the class loader to load the resources from the workspace. So maybe the issue is that some of the resources are not mapped and correctly?

Comment: tried both, with and without JRebel, either way I got the message about the missing file

Comment: Depending on standalone or deployment configuration that you are using, the war file may be sitting in the respective content directory. Check the question related to content directory here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089387/where-is-deployed-content-for-jboss-as-7. Also check the last segment stanalone.xml or domain.xml which will have information on the content directories.

Comment: @SureshKoya I dont' get what you mean, can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @SureshKoya found it in the standalone.xml you where right, please post an answer so that I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on standalone or deployment configuration that you are using, the war file may be sitting in the respective content directory. Check the question related to content directory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089387/where-is-deployed-content-for-jboss-as-7) Also check the last segment stanalone.xml or domain.xml which will have information on the content directories.

Comment: The solution was to remove the necessary section in the standalone-full.xml (or standalone.xml / domain.xml, depending on your setup), Eclipse doesn't need this entry because it copies the sources over to the deployment folder. IntelliJ obviously needs it.